# Character - Walk not Slide

Tags: animation

Quick info.

I'm trying to get my character to walk along a road.
And turn around and sit down on a bench.

My problem is. Is that my character slips. and do not walk
I get the legs to move. but when "he" takes a step so slide one leg forward. It's like he standing on ice.
I can not think of what I might have done wrong.

You can look at this to see. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxaO0HtoK5UgcjJVQ3BXMGd6MDQ/view?usp=sharing

How do I post my Blender file here?
As you can see closer what is wrong.

//
Robin W

Comment: You can upload the blend to http://www.pasteall.org/blend then paste the link in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your walk cycle is too slow. Basically, the guy is going twice to three times the distance he should per step.

To fix: either speed up the animation, or slow down the movement until it appears that the dude is moving right again. This may take some trial and error.

Also, there's pretty much no realistic way that avoids sliding to move a lego figure besides having his entire upper body rock back with each step. it'll look like he's ice skating until you fix the fact that both feet are on the ground at the same time. The foot that comes forward to take a step needs to be aerial-ized. I realize that this is hard for a guy with no knees but there are ways. You might want to check youtube to see how others have done it.

Comment: Okay, thank you.- Vince Scalia
I understand now. I'll slow down a bit. and he'll slip a little.
will probably be for the best. anyway this is my first animation I do. so it need not be perfect the first time.

Of course it can not be absolutely perfect if he does not have knees.
Did not think about it.
But as you say.
To get it well. it will take time.
I'm not one who needs perfection.
Good will do well for me. :)
But thanks for your reply. I was much helped by it.

Comment: No problem Rob. Glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

For this problem I wrote the [NoSlide](https://github.com/grgr/no_slide) addon for blender. 
With it you can define for your walk action the frames for each foot in which it should rest on the ground. Like this the character mesh will move in space exactly the changed distance between the foot and the root but the foot will rest.

Comment: Just linking to your addon (even if it answers the question) is not a good answer. Please add more info here. Even if everything is explained at the link location, SE wants to make sure that this answer can stand on its own. You also might want to add a that you created the addon.

Comment: Hey @David I updated the answer